# Is a selector an object?

Tags: objective-c

From Apple's Obj-C documentation:

> If the method returns an object, then a message sent to nil returns 0
>   (nil). For example:
>
> ```
>    Person *motherInLaw = [[aPerson spouse] mother];
> ```
>
> If the spouse object here is nil, then mother is sent to nil and the method returns
>   nil.

so `spouse` here can be an object? If it is an object, must it be a selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A selector is like a class method in a C++ class, it's a name of a method you call, with you defining the number and type of parameters it'll accept. It isn't an object at all. In the example above, "spouse" is a method name you call. It is never an object.

Edit:

The code

```
Person *motherInLaw = [[aPerson spouse] mother];
```

can be expanded to this:

```
Person *theSpouse = [aPerson spouse];
Person *motherInLaw = [theSpouse mother];
```

As you see, the "mother" method is called on the return value of the "spouse" method. This should clear any confusion.

Comment: So the document is basically wrong to call `spouse` an "object"?

Comment: When the document says "the `spouse` object", it's shorthand for "the object returned by the `spouse` method". That's kosher, if a bit of an oversimplification.

Answer (score 0):

The document is in fact correct. That is just the syntax of objective-c. In fact, aPerson is calling the getter method for spouse in this instance. If spouse has not been set at the time this is called, it will return nil, at which point sending the getter method for mother to spouse results in a method call to nil.

What you are seeing is indeed a method - just a method that returns an object of type spouse, and the poster above me has already described what a selector is.

Comment: So I'm confused as to why you refer to "spouse" as an object. It refers to a method of `aPerson` so why would it make sense to say that `spouse` is a type? `spouse` is not a type in this case, the type is not specified!

Comment: Spouse is some sort of property or object of the class that contains this code. The code above from apple's documentation is basically saying this: get the property (object) of spouse from aPerson, then if that object is not nil, get the property (object) of mother from spouse of aPerson. It's then assigned to mother in law! It's all just getter methods here that return objects.